# Сравнение двух одинаковых чисел дает ложь PHP

Tags: php, if

Дано:

1. массив чисел типа:
   $fields = array(510811, 506245, 486535, 489207, 497719, 510893, 514509);
2. Двухмерный массив, в котором вложенные массивы могут иметь поле 'field_id' равное одному из чисел п.1.

Цикл foreach перебирает вложенные массивы, а в нем еще один foreach перебирает значения $fields (так было нужно, я знаю про поиск в массиве) и сравнивает со значением интересующего поля.

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
foreach ($l['custom_fields_values'] as $cf) {
     foreach ($fields as $fl) {
        if ($fl == $cf['field_id']) {
```

При совпадающих значениях if не срабатывает. Переменные проверял по всякому, обе - int, доступны, одинаковы.

Comment: Каковы ваши доказательства?

Comment: vardump в студию

Comment: Вот дамп очередной итерации, в которой есть совпадение:
int(510811) =>> int(510811) , int(506245) , int(486535) , int(489207) , int(497719) , int(510893), int(514509).
Дошел до того, что проверял их на разность равную нулю - все равно всегда срабатывает отрицательная ветка, хотя вывод показывал ту самую нулевую разность.

Comment: Дампьте значения с условия, явно где-то допустили ошибку и сравниваете число с null или чем ещё

Comment: Это дамп непосредственно перед сравнением, с переменными больше ничего не происходит
```
foreach ($l['custom_fields_values'] as $cf) {            var_dump($cf['field_id']);
            foreach ($fields as $fl) {
                var_dump($fl);
                if ($fl == $cf['field_id']) {
                    $res[$i][$fl] = $cf['values'][0]['value'];
                }
                else {
                    $res[$i][$fl] = "-";
                }
            }
        }
```
Вот весь проблемный блок

Comment: Код в комментариях нечитаем. Отредактируйте вопрос и приложите дамп и код туда.

Comment: Впрочем уже так можно сказать что `$cf['field_id']` не число, а, видимо, ассоциативный массив.